# Process States in Operating System

Tags: operating-system

Are there any situations where a process can directly go from blocked to running(skipping ready) or from ready to blocked(skipping running)?

I think, in a single tasking system where only one process runs at a time, a process can directly go from blocked to running state because it has to be ready state only when there is some other process using the CPU at the moment.

But I am not sure about the other situation (ready to blocked).

Comment: blocked>running is a valid transition, sure. If a core is free, or the signaling thread needs to be preempted, then it will happen.  ready>blocked is more difficult to pin down: depends on the definition of 'blocked'.  For instance, a ready thread may be suspended before a core becomes available to run it,  Whether you consider that suspended state as 'blocked' or not, I'm not sure.

Comment: I am more interested in transition between processes and not threads. But still, in what situation would a ready thread be suspended before a core becomes available to it?

Comment: What?  Processes don't have execution and so cannot have states like 'ready' or 'blocked'.  ' in what situation ....' well, you think of one!  Some debugger thread suspends it, possibly, whatever, does it matter?  Some other thread suspended it for some reason.